# Avro schema not compatible

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I have a JSON Avro schema that is quite large, we need to evolve it and have added a lot more fields into it. I thought I had given them all default values and we are using BACKWARD compatibility. When I try to evolve the schema I get the error `This schema is incompatible with the latest version`

Is there a way I can get an intuitive error message that will give me some indication of why in the schema won't evolve?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can use the compatibility API to test the two versions and making changes accordingly before registering the schema: https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#id1

Comment: Would be useful if you could show the diff between schemas

Comment: The schemas were big and had lots of changes, I got it sorted there was some null value coming in the payload which hadn't got null as a type in the schema. It would be useful though if there was some indication back in the error to where the schema was giving an issue.